# wcf data services - passing extra params on save changes

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I have an existing web application that I want to wrap with WCF Data Services, to give it an OData input/output formatting.

in retrieving records, I can send whatever I like (myusername = "blabala", mycurrentusersession = "23434sdfgdf" and so on...). But in "SaveChanges" I do not control what is sent - though, I realy need the ability to supply the existing application :
  - my current user session 
  - the specific retrieve state key (my existing application is stateful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add these values in header of the outgoing request.

Suppose, you did "`Add Service Reference`" in your Client app, of your `WCF-DataService`.

then inside `Reference.cs` of the service(on the client), search for `OnContextCreated` event:

and then, add a handler to `SendingRequest` event

```
partial void OnContextCreated() 
{ 
   this.SendingRequest += Entity_SendingRequest; 
}
```

and inside `Entity_SendingRequest` you can add headers.

```
void Entity_SendingRequest(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs e) 
{ 
   e.RequestHeaders.Add("myusername", "blabala");
   e.RequestHeaders.Add("mycurrentusersession", "23434sdfgdf");
}
```

which you can very easily process at the Server End i.e. in the DataContext of WCF-DataService.

you can also pass a `CookieContainer`. That's the basis of Forms Authentication for WCF-Data Services.

```
void Entity_SendingRequest(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs e) 
{ 
   CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
   foreach (var cc in _cookies)
   {
       Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cc.Key, cc.Value.Value);
       cookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://localhost", UriKind.Absolute), cookie);
   }
   var cookieHeader = cookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri("http://localhost", 
                                                            UriKind.Absolute));
    e.RequestHeaders["Cookie"] = cookieHeader;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 2 more questions: how will this work in a web client? how can I send my token from server to client on retrieve, without changing my entity format?

Comment: its even easier to do it through the WebClient. `client.Headers.Add("myusername", "blabala");`. and then you can process it inside OnStartProcessingRequest

Comment: thank you.Still looking for a way to gend my token to the client.

Comment: what you mean? you're not able to fetch the headers on the server ? or you are not able to send a response token from the server to the client?

Comment: I'm not able to send "stateId" from server to client on first retrieve